# scale bone to negative didn't work?

Tags: animation, armature, scale, 2d

I've tried looking almost everywhere , but no one seems to actually ask this question . I've created a 2D character in blender and rigged it .

My question is , why can't I scale non-root bones to negative values ?

Since im doing 2D , it's common to flip some body parts and stuff , but I've tried to flip non root bones (the head) with the child (hair and face) with   <-1> , but it snap back to positive scaling , the flipping works with the root bone but it seems it didn't work with individual child ? Then what workaround I could do to this problem ?

Comment: In 2D shouldn't scale of -1 be the same thing as rotation normal 180°? Assuming that the bone is in the same plane as the bodypart it controls.
Also, I'm not sure what you mean by none-root, I tried connected bones and their scales stays at 1, -1, 1 or -1,-1,-1.

Answer (score 1):

Well , I hope this gif explain better , I mean the root bone is the main (first) parent , and the non root is the child , [bone] is the parent and [bone.001] is the child .[image]